# How to select one radio button in Android

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

1. Here is my xml view
2. Within the horizontalScrollView I have images and radio button.
3. I want to select only one radio button.But here I can select more than one   radio button. Please help me how to do that.

---

```
      <HorizontalScrollView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="vertical" >

              <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/partly"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               />

          <RadioButton
              android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>


             <LinearLayout>

              <ImageView../>

              <RadioButton../>

             </LinearLayout>


       </LinearLayout>

       </HorizontalScrollView>
```

---

Comment: you can use radiogroup

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your xml code is that you want something scrollable views out of which only one can be selected. For which you are using RadioButton which is usually used to force user to select only one item.

You can achieve such functionality with radio buttons using RadioGroup.

But again if you use RadioGroup it can holde only RadioButtons as a child. While your case is different. You have LinearLayout as a child of ScrollView and RadioButton is a child of that LinearLayout

What you should do

1) Set some radio button checked as a default. And assign its index to some variable i.e. activePosition

2) Now When user taps on some other radio button you should set checked property that old RadioButton as false and change the activePosition=currentlyTappedRadioButton's view's position

Comment: Can you please give me some code example. I am new to android.

Comment: Yea I can write a small code on behalf of you. First Can you edit the question and add your Java code inside i.e. how you are adding view in Horizontal ScrollView ?